A6100 wifi adapter drivers not working on Ubuntu 24.04
I have Ubuntu 24.04 and a A6100 wifi stick
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0846:9052 NetGear, Inc. A6100 AC600 DB Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8811AU]
I've tried installing tons of different drivers and none of them seem to work for me, eg:

A6100 wifi adapter not installing correctly with known techniques
Netgear A6100[RTL8811AU] wireless adapter not working after update on Ubuntu 22.04

Output for dkms status:
rtl8812au/4.3.14: added 
rtl8821cu/5.12.0.4, 6.8.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed

Have you looked into the maker of the stick that there is a driver for Ubuntu 24.04?

USB key are usually very poorly designed, I do not recommend using it, it always end in a drama.

@David I have looked into the maker and they dont have official support for linux but ive seen plenty of people online who got it to work.

Well all I can say then is good luck.
